# Multiple linq queries or just build a SQL view?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq

I have a mvc view that requires data from 5 different DB tables.  I currently have a big LINQ query that joins all the tables and returns the results, works fine.  However, I am wondering if it would better to build a DB view to make the LINQ query simple.

Comment: You don't provide any code, so all we could do is give generic answers, or oppinion based answer or just wild (educated) guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying 5 tables via a single query isn't *necessarily* a problem. It depends on a ton of external factors like how performant is your database setup and the characteristics of the tables themselves: are they huge with millions of rows or only a few hundred?

Assuming it *is* a problem, causing excessive load on your database or long page load times, then yes, you might want to look into an alternative solution, but a view is almost certainly not the right choice.

Views have a very key negative in that they cannot have keys nor indexes. That means unless you plan to just return everything in the view, it will almost always be slower to query into a view than even doing joins across tables. Frankly, I've pretty much never found a good use for a database view in a web application context. Maybe they work in other environments, such as reporting, but other than that, they're useless. If you need an alternative to Entity Framework, use a stored procedure.

Comment: I was under the impression that the query engine used the indexes of the tables that the view was composed of?

Answer (score 0):

Since your objective is performance, keep with the 5 joins. You could enable SQL Profiler and track the query that is being generated by EF. Probably, if you write the query manually and then send to EF execute it, you'll get a better performance too.